# How can I programmatically add content to a Wagtail StreamField?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm doing a migration from an old site, and I need to programmatically add raw html to a `StreamField` on a Wagtail page.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make sure that `RawHTMLBlock` is enabled on your `StreamField`, and then insert it there.  The process for adding content to the field is as follows:

```
import json

original_html = '<p>Hello, world!</p>'

# First, convert the html to json, with the appropriate block type
raw_json = json.dumps([{'type': 'raw_html', 'value': original_html}])

# Load Wagtail page
my_page = Page.objects.get(id=1)
# Assuming the stream field is called 'body',
# add the json string to the field
my_page.body = raw_json
my_page.save()
```

You can use this approach to add other kinds of blocks to the `StreamField` - just make sure you create a list of dictionaries with the appropriate block type, convert it to json, and save.

Comment: Note that as of at least Wagtail 1.5, you need not use a JSON string created from an array of dictionaries. You can instead use an array of tuples directly, like so: `my_page.body = [('raw_html', original_html)]`